# Will repeated, identical expressions get processed again?

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL server and I was trying to use an alias in a where clause and then I realized the order of processing makes it hard to do that, so I used this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (SELECT LEFT(fiscal,4) AS fiscalyear FROM
Transactions )      fiscalyears
WHERE fiscalyear >= '2009'
```

I could have used this too, as it works too:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(fiscal, 4) FROM Transactions
WHERE LEFT(fiscal, 4) >= '2009'
```

Now, the question I have about this is: Is one better than the other method? The query execution plan looks identical for both (I don't know how to read a query plan in depth at all, just saw that it looks similar in both of these cases). 
This is just one small table with small number of rows but will there be noticeable differences with huge amounts of data?

Comment: fiscal is a string storing just something like '201201' for just year and month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server is usually pretty smart about not computing the same thing multiple times at the same level of scope. So you should only see one compute scalar in either variation.

In fact, even in this more complex case, SQL Server still manages to only require a single compute scalar, and all the costing is the same:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(fiscalyear,6) 
FROM dbo.Transactions
  WHERE LEFT(fiscalyear,5) >= '2009'
  OR LEFT(fiscalyear,4)>'2008';
```

(And it should go without saying that the better approach - if `fiscalyear` is date/time - is to have a sargable where clause, like `WHERE fiscalyear >= '20090101'`. If it is a string, then like @ypercube mentions above, you don't need the left expression - `WHERE fiscalyear >= '2009'` does the same thing.)

But as a generic answer, if you ever have any doubts about this, run the two queries with actual execution plan turned on, and see if they're different. However, I will say that the subquery form is often used not to prevent an expression from being evaluated multiple times, but to avoid having to *type it* multiple times. And even if you haven't typed it multiple times, there are still cases where it can still be *evaluated* multiple times. So there is no absolute "this method is better than the other one."

Comment: So sorry, the other one was supposed to have DISTINCT too! That is cool, I had no idea it won't compute queries again. Will this hold true of other cases too, where, say there is a query inside an IN clause of a where clause (this query uses a user defined function for example) rather than doing a join on the function?

Comment: @Ravi No, this isn't something that is always true in all scenarios. The point is that the execution plan certainly gives you an easy way to check, in every single scenario. There is no magic blanket answer and there is no reason to enumerate every single scenario...

Comment: Okay, thanks, I think I will need to read more on execution plans and then see for myself how things are working with different scenarios. This derived table way was something I found as an answer here on stackexchange, which was a solution to using an alias in a where clause.

Comment: It also prevents you from repeating the same expression in the code twice (probably more the intended benefit), regardless of whether it would end up being evaluated once or twice.

Comment: Yes, in very large queries with other column operations like, say, cases being used, it would make sense to have this, right?

Comment: @Ravi it can, but again, the better benefit is to simplify the code. Even with `CASE` expressions, CTEs, derived tables, etc. you have no control over the order of operations. You'll often see errors, for example, for string columns that are attempted to be converted to a date, and the errors occur on values that should have been filtered out in the where clause inside a CTE or subquery.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and explanation of everything!